# What is the benefit of using a fanout micro-service

Tags: node.js, design-patterns, microservices

I was just reading this article **[HERE](https://interviewnoodle.com/twitter-system-architecture-8dafce16aec4)**. Basically the user suggesting that a sample twitter architecture be split up into multiple micro-services , see the diagram below :-

[image: Sample twitter architecture].

However, there is this one service though which i see multiple calls being passed though , not directly through user action but it sits in between. the `Fanout Service`, what exactly is a fanout service ? what purpose does it serve. So far what i understand is it sends data to multiple other services, But whats the advantage ? When exactly do we leverage a Fanout micro-service ? What value does it add ?